# Where I can find a list of "mysqldump" exit codes?

Tags: mysql, exit-code

I know that `exit code = 0` means `No error`.

I got `exit code = 2`. What does it means ?

Where I can see the complete list of `mysqldump` exit codes ?

Answer (score 42):

Taken from client/mysqldump.c in MySQL 5.1.59:

```
#define EX_USAGE 1
#define EX_MYSQLERR 2
#define EX_CONSCHECK 3
#define EX_EOM 4
#define EX_EOF 5 /* ferror for output file was got */
#define EX_ILLEGAL_TABLE 6
```

Skimming through the source, EX_MYSQLERR seems to be used mostly for errors from the server, but also in case malloc fails. CONSCHECK seems to stand for consistency checks. EX_EOM is returned for some _alloc calls too - "End Of Memory"?

Answer (score 15):

Exit code 2 often occurs when the dump could not be completed due to privilege problems; for example, if the user does not have the `LOCK TABLES` privilege, or the supplied password was wrong.

Comment: This was one of my problems when I tried to dump a remote database, but I had to resolve another `Skipping dump data for table` as well. +1 anyways!

Answer (score 5):

This is worth noting that if you use `mysqldump` in php function `exec`, `shell_exec` or `system` as command it will return 02 exit code if you do not have permissions to write file into selected location.

In my case command:

```
mysqldump '-uUSER' '-pPASS' DATABASE > /home/USER/LOCATION/dump.sql
```

When called from php did not work. It was solved after adding proper write permissions to LOCATION folder.

I solved it by checking what was sent as output when calling command:

```
myslqdump
```

and after it:

```
mysqldump '-uUSER' '-pPASS' DATABASE
```

In both cases command gave proper response in 2nd argument of `exec` function.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason might be a password with too special chars, which was used unescaped on the console (since you use `mysqldump`). The process returns the error code 2 too. I have this problem from time to time. Wrapping params at least in quotes / double-quotes helps often: Instead `-u... -p...` and so on, using `"-u..." "-p..."` eliminates many problems. However it is not a perfect solution (if the same type of quotes are used).

It can also be an OS dependent problem. MS Windows for example uses variables, like `%MYVAR%` which seems not be able to be escaped at all (at least some sources like the [PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) mentions this).

Comment: Thanks - the password being too special was the problem for me, although the quotes didn't help. I just simplified the password and now all good.