# mysqldump returns code 6 when run from java, but the same command works fine from command line

Tags: java, process, mysql, runtime.exec

When I run the same command from Java via Runtime.getRuntime I get the return code 6. The same command works fine from command line:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mysqldumpCommand);
int processComplete = process.waitFor();
```

For those 2 commands I get the return code 6 when run from java and no dump. The work fine from command line(I don't have a password on the local env.)

```
mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost dbname > c:\temp\dumpfile.sql
mysqldump --user=root --password="" --host=localhost dbname > c:\temp\dumpfile.sql
```

When deliberately put wrong password I get return code 2 in java, and a connection error in command line:

```
mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost dbname > c:\temp\dumpfile.sql
```

The return codes as I found them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846022/where-i-can-find-a-list-of-mysqldump-exit-codes):

```
Taken from client/mysqldump.c in MySQL 5.1.59:

#define EX_USAGE 1
#define EX_MYSQLERR 2
#define EX_CONSCHECK 3
#define EX_EOM 4
#define EX_EOF 5 /* ferror for output file was got */
#define EX_ILLEGAL_TABLE 6
```

How come I get (error) return code 6 when running the same command in java and works fine from command line?

Later Edit: I try it from Windows.

Comment: 1) Go through the Java World article linked from the [exec info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) 2) Implement all the recommendations (that will probably solve the problem or give you enough information to solve the problem). 3) Then join us in the 3rd millennium and swap the `Runtime.exec()` for a `new ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Runtime.exec` is not a shell](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), so redirections with > and < won't work. Currently the command is passing `>` to `mysqldump`, which interprets it as the name for the table you want to export. (Hence return code 6, "illegal table".)

There are two solutions:

1. Run a shell. Use this command instead of the one you have:

   ```
   cmd.exe /c "mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost dbname > c:\temp\dumpfile.sql"
   ```
2. Write the output from the command to a file yourself, with `Process.getInputStream()`.

Comment: If the questioner is using Windows, it's probably better to use `cmd.exe /c` instead of `sh -c`.

Comment: Ah, good point @Luke, I hadn't noticed the `c:\\` in the path.

Comment: it works fine on windows, i suppose using sh -c instead of cmd /c will do the trick on linux.

Answer (score 2):

The mysqldump now supports `--result-file=`

So it would look like this.

```
mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost dbname --result-file=c:\temp\dumpfile.sql
```