# MySQLDump error code 6 when running MySQLDump via Java

Tags: java, runtime, mysql

This is my code:

```
String cmd = "\"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqldump\" -h www.anonymizeddomain.com -u root -proot anon_thisdb > anon_thisdb.sql\"";
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            Print(cmd);

            InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");

            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                 System.out.println(line);

            System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

It exits with error code 6 and idk why. The output i get from the console is this:

```
<OUTPUT>
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.13, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: www.anonymizeddomain.com    Database: anon_thisdb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.32-cll-lve

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
</OUTPUT>
Process exitValue: 6
```

What the popsicle slices am i doing wrong?!

I put the escape characters in the string so i wouldn't get errors, but yet i got errors :\ what the fudge? :\

Comment: This is what you're looking for my friend https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464074/1639291 Best Regards!

Comment: Interesting and makes sense.

Comment: I already tried this, but what this one returns in the console is "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Did you put the \" escaped? that happens because it only reads **C:\Program** instead of **C:\Program Files...**, and the only way to read it complete is to put it between ""

Comment: What if you put only **mysqldump** instead of the whole programpath... isn't it on your PATH enviroment variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqldump returns code 6 when run from java, but the same command works fine from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463990/mysqldump-returns-code-6-when-run-from-java-but-the-same-command-works-fine-fro)