# How to find that mysql backup is successful?

Tags: mysql

I am using WAMP on windows 7. I created a windows batch file backup.bat with following code:

```
    C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqldump -uroot -hlocalhost dbcreditors >     C:\wamp\www\bkp_dbcreditors.sql
```

When I run backup.bat a command prompt flashes and backup is taken but it does not tell whether backup was successful or not.

Any suggestion to get confirmation?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846022/where-i-can-find-a-list-of-mysqldump-exit-codes

Comment: You can check `mysqldump` exit code (not sure how microsoft name it), also you could try to restore your dump into another database and run application tests on that.

Comment: Why? You can schedule MySQL backups directly via the MySQL Administator. No need for .bat files at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify it manually, add a `PAUSE` at the end of the script which makes the prompt stay until you have the time to read possible error messages.

Comment: sorry PAUSE does not work. Could you please write syntax

Comment: @user3762808 The syntax is as follows: `PAUSE`. Please. This is a standard DOS .bat file command. Look it up.