# mysqldump dump via php exec works for 1st db but not next 3

Tags: php, exec, mysql

I have four databases which I am trying to backup in php using exec(mysqldump...)
I am using the following code,

```
$command = 'mysqldump  --single-transaction --comments --dump-date --host='.$host[$db].' --user='.$dbuser[$db].' --password='.$dbpass[$db].' '.$dbname[$db].' | zip > '.$filepath;
exec($command, $_messages, $result);
if($result)
{
echo '<p class="success">Backup for database '.$dbname[$db].' complete. Located at: '.$filepath.'';
}
else 
{
```

echo 'Backup for database '.$dbname[$db].' failed

';
   }

The $host, $dbname, etc are same variables I use for connecting to the databases for normal access, so I know they are valid.  I was under the impression that 3rd argument on the exec() function was *True* if successful, *False* otherwise.  The dumps are cycled through using the $db variable, so the commands issued are identical in format, but obviously with different details for each database.  The results are as follows,

- Database A dump works fine, but $result is returned as *False*
- Database B dump produces a file, but no contents and $result is returned as *False*
- Database c dump produces a file, but no contents and $result is returned as *False*
- Database D dump apparently works ($result *True*) but produces no file.

So I am beginning the think the correct interpretation of $result is 0 for success.

There is no difference if the databases are processed in a loop or processed individually.  No problem in producing the dumps via phpMyAdmin and the dump for database A tallys with the phpMyAdmin dump.

I'm on a shared hosting platform running php 5.4 and MySQL 5.6.30 with cPanel.

Anyone got any thoughts as to what might be happening?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think -1 means false for this function. Similar to `strpos()` but this is just off of a hunch

Comment: as far as i know `$result` will be populated with the return code of the `mysqldump` binary and not related to the `exec` function status code.

Comment: see this list http://stackoverflow.com/a/7495907/5043552 of *error* codes, on success it will return `0`

Comment: Thanks.  I had return values of 0 for the ones that supposedly failed and 1 for the one that supposedly worked.  The real problem is why the first dump worked and the others didn't.